# Is there any structure in linux kernel for processes sharing a virtual memory area?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

The kernel maintains a structure for each process ([task_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.4#L1264)) and the corresponding memory descriptor ([mm_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm_types.h?v=3.4#L288)) which further has a member **mm_users** that indicates the number of users sharing that user space.

My question is, for any particular memory descriptor, is there a list/structure that the kernel maintains for all the processes that share the memory descriptor?

NOTE: I am working with linux kernel v3.4